# How to forcefully timeout a Node.js Oracle DB connection when it doesn't return

Tags: node.js, oracle, npm, oracle11g

I am using Npm Orcale in nodejs, my compiler going to connect orcaledb ,  its hang thread  to getting connection . i want to timeout forcefully because my client doesn't wait more then 15 seconds . how to this in my code. i tried and google more then 8 hour but not success anyone help me this

```
 async _getConnection (reqId = '') {   
    const connection = await this.connectionPool.getConnection()
      .catch(error => this.logger.error('API Error _getConnection Oracle DB Error : ', error))
      this.logger.info('API _getConnection Oracle Connection ', connection)
      connection.callTimeout = config.get('db.sqlTimeOut') * 1000

    return connection
  }
```

on this line compiler is hang and doesn't return back , not catch not error getting from orcale

```
const connection = await this.connectionPool.getConnection()
```

Answer (score 2):

Now you can use the `callTimeout` property as a straight number, in milliseconds.
Here's an example for it:

```
import * as OracleDB from "oracledb";

export class OracleDBHandler {
  static async execute(query: string): Promise<OracleDB.Result<unknown>> {
    try {
      const connection = await OracleDB.getConnection({
        user: process.env.RDS_USERNAME,
        password: process.env.RDS_PASSWORD,
        connectionString: `${process.env.RDS_HOSTNAME}/${process.env.RDS_SID}`,
      });
      connection.callTimeout = 10 * 1000; // Reduced the timeout to 10 secs

      const rows = await connection.execute(query, [], {
        outFormat: OracleDB.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT,
      });
      await connection.close();

      return rows;
    } catch (exception) {
      console.error("Got an error during OracleDb connection: ", exception);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some [node-oracledb documentation hints on this](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#connectionha).  Connection timeouts are handled by Oracle's SQL*Net layer, so look at all the SQL*Net options such as [SQLNET.OUTBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/netrf/parameters-for-the-sqlnet.ora.html#GUID-0857C817-675F-4CF0-BFBB-C3667F119176).

For example, if Node.js is using Oracle Client libraries 19c or later, you could use the ['Easy Connect Plus'](https://download.oracle.com/ocomdocs/global/Oracle-Net-19c-Easy-Connect-Plus.pdf) syntax: `"mydbmachine.example.com/orclpdb1?connect_timeout=15"` for `connectionString`.